# Turn of Htaccess Caching in Admin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel, caching

I have a Laravel development. I want the `htaccess` file to work on the front end, but I don't want it to cache anything in the admin. All admin pages are in the directory `/home/` - I want to make the code shown below NOT apply to anything in this folder.

How can I achieve this?

In my `htaccess` file is the following code:

```
    <ifModule mod_expires.c>
      ExpiresActive On
      ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
      ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
      ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
    </ifModule>

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
      <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private"
      </filesMatch>
      <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
      </filesMatch>
      Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
      Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
      Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
    </IfModule>

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$" no-gzip

AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Note: There is no actual admin folder called "home" so i can't make another htaccess file. When i do make a "home" folder it creates a strange error and loop because all admin folders in laravel are dynamic and controlled by the routes file.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new .htaccess file in you /home/ directory where is located pages for administration use only with the simple content:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive Off
</ifModule>
```

And you need to check if in Apache or Nginx configuration of virtual host is allowed to Override All

Comment: The home directory isn't a real structure, none of the admin structure has a real folder hierarchy.  i don't have access to apache configuration. I added the home folder to see what would happen and i got stuck in a loop

Comment: Each next .htaccess file in each sub folder override rules from the previous .htaccess file. You need to create a new .htaccess file in the admin content directory to override rules that is for fronted.

Comment: In this case admin folders are dynamic, so i can't make such a folder. Although it would be the perfect solution if i could do such a thing